# Question about functions and input/output

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I am given a formula $f(x) = {1\over(x^2-2)}$. I need to determine if it is a function for f: $\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ and if it is a function for f: $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$

For the first part, I said that it wasn't a function because it is undefined for $-\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt2$. Is this correct? I realize that for each input, there can only be one output, but what if there is no output? My instructor never went over this.

For the second part, it is a function, as every input produces an output (regardless if it is unique) that is in $\mathbb{R}$.

Are these answers correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct and seem to understand the issue well.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in both of your assertions.  The numbers $x = \pm \sqrt{2}$ are real numbers that are not integers for which the expression $f(x)$ is not defined.

More formally, write $\operatorname{Dom}(f)$ for the natural *domain* of the function $f$, namely, the set of real numbers for which the function is defined.  For this particular function,
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Dom}(f) &= \left\{ x \in \Bbb{R} \mid x^2 \ne 2 \right\} \\
&= \left\{ x \in \Bbb{R} \mid x \ne \pm \sqrt{2} \right\} \subset \Bbb{R}\\
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Dom}(f) \cap \Bbb{Z} = \Bbb{Z}.
$$